# Using URL.Action inside a LINQ select method

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, url-action

I want to create a view model that holds list items, and each item will hold the edit and delete action URL so I have the following code:

```
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            AdministrationViewModel model = new AdministrationViewModel();
            using (var _context = new CamelotFaultManagementEntities())
            {
                model.FaultTypes = new ListViewModel()
                {
                    ListTitle = AdministrationStrings.FaultTypesAdministrationTab,
                    AddNewItemURL = "#",
                    AddNewItemButtonTitle = SharedStrings.Add + " " + SharedStrings.FaultType,
                    ListItems = _context.FaultTypes.Select(type => new ListItemViewModel() { 
                        ListItemID = type.FaultTypeID,
                        ListItemName = type.FaultTypeName,
                        ListItemDescription = type.FaultTypeDescription,
                        DeleteActionURL = @Url.Action("DeleteFaultType","Administration", new {FaultTypeID = type.FaultTypeID}),
                        EditActionURL = @Url.Action("EditFaultType", "Administration", new { FaultTypeID = type.FaultTypeID }),
                    }).ToList()
                };
            }
            return View("Administration",model);
        }
```

The problem is that I receive an error during runtime

> LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.String
>   Action(System.String, System.String, System.Object)' method, and this
>   method cannot be translated into a store expression.

Any way to overcome this... i really don't want to start creating these URLs by myself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is here:

```
DeleteActionURL = @Url.Action("DeleteFaultType","Administration", /*...*/),
EditActionURL = @Url.Action("EditFaultType", "Administration", /*...*/)
```

LINQ tries to create expression tree, which would be mapped to SQL code, but it doesn't know how to map `Url.Action`. One way to fix this would be *change* Linq to Entities to Linq to Objects, which can be done using `ToList()` method on your entity:

```
ListItems = _context.FaultTypes.ToList().Select(i => ...)
```